# drupal 7 'views'. Use the context filter to path 'directory /% /%'

Tags: views, theming, commerce, 7

**Site Drupal 7 Commerce.**

path pattern catalog category - '`category / [term: name] / [term: tid]`'
To display the product catalog categories set view '`catalog_view`' with parameters:

Page settings: path: '`category /% /%`', where the first argument - raw name term, the second argument - id term.
The Contextual filters are two filters:

1) Global: Null

[image]

2) Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)

[image]

I need to first parameter of the Drupal path ignored, and the second was used for the filter. But it is impossible.

When outputting through a "**Preview with contextual filters:**" everything is OK, displays all products in the category (for example, '`category / Tables / 109`').

But when you enter the same path in the address bar - miracles. Shows the correct goods category (`products with tag id = 109`)
but is used template `'page - taxonomy - term.tpl.php`'.

If an error in the name of the category (for example, '`category / Tab - les / 109`') displayed products with tag `id = 109` and used our view '`catalog_view`'.

Question two:

1) How do I get on the category / Tables / 109 displayed view '`catalog_view`' (ignore the path catalog and filter the first argument to the second argument).

2) How Drupal can trace routing? For example, I set the path '`category / Tables / 109`'
and I would like to see how the first through Drupal alias returns the path `taxonomy / term / 109`
like looking for a match this way what the views. As it is all a matter amenable to debug?